# Is a matrix of subset indicator totally unimodular?

Tags: optimization, combinations, discrete-optimization, total-unimodularity

> Let $S=\{1,\ldots, m\}$ and $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ be subsets of S. Let $B=(b_{ij})_{m\times n} = \{0,1\}_{m\times n}$ be a matrix such that 
>   $$ b_{ij}= \begin{cases}
>         1 & i \in A_j \\
>         0 & \mbox{otherwise}
>     \end{cases}$$ 
>   Is matrix $B$ totally unimodular?

I do not know whether $B$ is totally unimodular. Can anyone have an answer? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does (totaly) unimodular mean?

Comment: Please look at here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $B$ is not TUM (totally unimodular). As an example you can take $m=3, n=4$ and $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{1,2\}$, $A_3=\{1,3\}$, $A_4=\{2,3\}$. Then 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$det(\tilde{B})=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}=-2$$
On the other hand if $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{2\}$, $A_3=\{3\}$, $A_4=\{1,2,3\}$ then 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$ is TUM, because it has the *consecutive one’s* property on the columns (see   [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) for the definition). Therefore the TUM property of $B$ depends on the choose you make for the subsets of $S$.